# Is there a way to get field associated with content type?

Tags: nodes

I have to do some functionality with fields associated with a content type, this i have to do before creating content for it.

In custom module tried using node_type_load('digital_iq_2012'), this function loads content type details alone and not the fields associated.

Do we have a way to get the fields as well?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [field_info_instances('node', $content_type)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7).

With `field_info_instances('node', 'article')`, I get the following.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I guess **field_read_fields** will be nice : http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_read_fields/7